# What is the best way to convert an AsyncRead to a TryStream of bytes?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have an `AsyncRead` and want to convert it to a `Stream<Item = tokio::io::Result<Bytes>>` with tokio 0.2 and futures 0.3.

The best I've been able to do is something like:

```rust
use bytes::Bytes; // 0.4.12
use futures::stream::{Stream, TryStreamExt};; // 0.3.1
use tokio::{fs::File, io::Result}; // 0.2.4
use tokio_util::{BytesCodec, FramedRead}; // 0.2.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("some_file.txt").await?;
    let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new()).map_ok(|b| b.freeze());
    fn_that_takes_stream(stream)
}

fn fn_that_takes_stream<S, O>(s: S) -> Result<()>
where
    S: Stream<Item = Result<Bytes>>,
{
    //...
    Ok(())
}
```

It seems like there should be a simpler way; I'm surprised Tokio doesn't include a codec to get a stream of `Bytes` instead of `BytesMut` or that there isn't just an extension trait that provides a method to convert an `AsyncRead` into a `Stream`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use tokio 1.0 or 0.3, tokio-util now has [`tokio_util::io::ReaderStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.6.9/tokio_util/io/struct.ReaderStream.html) starting from version 0.4.

```rust
let file = File::open("some_file.txt").await?;
let stream = tokio_util::io::ReaderStream::new(file);
fn_that_takes_stream(stream)
```