# How do I convert a futures_io::AsyncRead to rusoto::ByteStream?

Tags: rust, rusoto

I am trying to build a service that pulls files from an SFTP server and uploads them to S3.

For the SFTP part, I am using [async-ssh2](https://docs.rs/async-ssh2/0.1.1-beta/async_ssh2/index.html), which gives me a file handler implementing [`futures::AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/futures-io/0.3.5/futures_io/trait.AsyncRead.html). Since these SFTP files may be quite large, I am trying to turn this `File` handler into a [`ByteStream`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.44.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html) that I can upload using Rusoto. It looks like a `ByteStream` can be initialized with a [`futures::Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures-core/0.3.5/futures_core/stream/trait.Stream.html).

My plan was to implement `Stream` on the `File` object (based on the code [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/convert-tokio-tcpstream-to-a-future-stream/32671/8)) to be compatible with Rusoto (code reproduced below for posterity):

```rust
use core::pin::Pin;
use core::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::{ready, stream::Stream};

pub struct ByteStream<R>(R);

impl<R: tokio::io::AsyncRead + Unpin> Stream for ByteStream<R> {
    type Item = u8;

    fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut buf = [0; 1];

        match ready!(Pin::new(&mut self.0).poll_read(cx, &mut buf)) {
            Ok(n) if n != 0 => Some(buf[0]).into(),
            _ => None.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Would this be a good way to go about doing this? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318460/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-asyncread-to-a-trystream-of-bytes), but it seems to be using [`tokio::io::AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html). Is using `tokio` the canonical way to go about doing this? If so, is there a way to convert from `futures_io::AsyncRead` to `tokio::io::AsyncRead`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the way I went about doing the conversion. I based it off the code above, except I used a larger buffer (8 KB) to reduce the number of network calls.

```rust
use bytes::Bytes;
use core::pin::Pin;
use core::task::{Context, Poll};
use futures::{ready, stream::Stream};
use futures_io::AsyncRead;
use rusoto_s3::StreamingBody;

const KB: usize = 1024;

struct ByteStream<R>(R);

impl<R: AsyncRead + Unpin> Stream for ByteStream<R> {
    type Item = Result<Bytes, std::io::Error>;

    fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut buf = vec![0_u8; 8 * KB];

        match ready!(Pin::new(&mut self.0).poll_read(cx, &mut buf[..])) {
            Ok(n) if n != 0 => Some(Ok(Bytes::from(buf))).into(),
            Ok(_) => None.into(),
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)).into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Allowing me to do this:

```rust
fn to_streamingbody(body: async_ssh2::File) -> Option<StreamingBody> {
    let stream = ByteStream(body);
    Some(StreamingBody::new(stream))
}
```

(note that `rusoto::StreamingBody` and `rusoto::ByteStream` are aliases)

Comment: Note that this will allocate and zero out an 8MB buffer every time `poll_next()` is called. It'd be good to avoid that expense, for instance by making `buf` a shared [thread local](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.thread_local.html) buffer. Also, 8MB is [probably much larger than you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811006/what-is-a-good-buffer-size-for-socket-programming).

Comment: Oh, cool! I had been trying to do that but didn't know how to get around the compiler error without an unsafe block. And thanks for the other link, will make those changes.

Comment: Updated to use an 8 KB buffer size; however, I am not sure how to get the thread_local working without copying (this might be close to necessitating a new question). `Bytes::from(buf: Vec<u8>)` needs ownership of the `Vec`, which we don't have when borrowing from a RefCell (so would need to clone). If we make the buf a `[u8]`, the only method I see in Bytes is `copy_from_slice` which again copies it.

Comment: On second thought it [may be impossible without GATs](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/12/10/async-interview-2-cramertj-part-2/): "The main concern that cramertj raised with [Stream] is that, like Iterator, it always gives ownership of each item back to its caller... In practice, many stream/iterator implementations would be more efficient if they could have some internal storage that they re-use over and over. For example, they might have an internal buffer, and when `poll_next` is called, they would give back (upon completion) a reference to that buffer."